# How to load certificate from pkcs#7 file?

Tags: go, certificate, pkcs#7

I have a pkcs7 file that contains a concatenation of 3 certificates in this order:
Leaf certificate ->
Intermediate CA ->
Root CA.

I am trying to write a go program that loads the certificate from the leaf certificate and takes the public key and the signature and my method does not work. Do you have any other suggestions of how i could do this? Am I doing something wrong?

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(certificate_path)
block, _ := pem.Decode(b)
if block == nil {
    panic("failed to parse certificate")
}

// get pkcs7 certificate
_, err = pkcs7.Parse(b)
if err != nil {
    panic("failed to parse certificate in pkcs7 format: " + err.Error())
}
```

This fails with the following error:

panic: failed to parse certificate in pkcs7 format: ber2der: BER tag length is more than available data

Does anyone have any idea how cand i parse certificate from a pkcs7 file in go? And then how take the key and the signature?

Comment: Could the `x509/CertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM` method be helpful?

Comment: I tried it and it does not work. It only works if i manually (using openssl in terminal) convert  the pkcs7 file to pem format.

Comment: You may have to use a 3rd party package for reading PKCS7 in Go (e.g. https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/fullsailor/pkcs7)

Comment: This is the one I am trying to use because I could not find anything else that might be useful. As you can see, I try loading the certificate using a function from the pkcs7 package "pkcs7.Parse(b)" an unfortunately it does not work. I can't tell what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The code I mentioned above works. Apparently the problem was with the format of the certificate, even though when inspecting the certificate type it is pkcs7. I tried converting it to pem and then back to pkcs7 and now the code above works, so I guess the format of the initial certificate is the problem. I don't know why tho.

This still does not solve my problem because i need to load the initial pkcs7 certificate in go...